# Infinum of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, supremum-and-infimum

Assume that $x > c > 0 $. Prove that $\displaystyle \inf\left(c/x \frac{e^{c/x}}{e^{c/x} - 1}\right) = 1$ without using limit.

However you are all allowed to use the theorem about the exponential function:
The exponential function $e:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has the following properties:

$1.~e^u < \frac1{1-u} $for all $u < 1$
$2.~e^u > 1 + u$ for all $u\in\mathbb R$
$3.~e^u $ is a growing function for all $u\in\mathbb R$
$4.~e^u > 0 $ for all $u\in\mathbb R$
$5.~e^u \cdot e^{-u} = 1 $ for all $u\in\mathbb R$

By using property 2 I get the following expression: 
$\displaystyle \inf\left(c/x \frac{e^{c/x}}{e^{c/x} - 1}\right) > c/x \frac{{1+c/x}}{e^{c/x}-1} $

But I don't get any further. If you have any hints please let me know.

Comment: You are computing the inf with $x$ in the interval $(0,c)$; it's easier to compute the inf of $\frac{te^t}{e^t-1}$, with $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: but x is not in the interval (0, c) since c/x is a positive number smaller than 1, that is x > c

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant $x\in(c,\infty)$. But the idea is the same.

Comment: thanks you're right, I wasted so many hours for this problem and you find a such easy solution, that's great. But do think it's possible to somehow show this without using L'Hospital's Rule. Is it possible to show this by using the properties of a exponential function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument which uses no limits and does not use L'Hopital's Rule. Only the stated properties of exponential function are uses. As mentioned in the comments the question is equivalent to showing that the infimum of $\frac {te^{t}} {e^{t}-1} $ ove $(0,1)$ is $1$. Now $\frac {te^{t}} {e^{t}-1} >1$ for all $t \in (0,1)$ by property 1). So the infimum is $\geq 1$. Suppose, if possible, the infimum is $1+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Then $\frac {te^{t}} {e^{t}-1} >1+\epsilon$ for all $t \in (0,1)$. This gives $e^{t} (1+\epsilon-t) < 1+\epsilon$. Now use property 2) to get  $(1+t) (1+\epsilon-t) < 1+\epsilon$. This simplifies to $\epsilon t <t^{2}$ or $\epsilon  <t$ for all $t \in (0,1)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although I don't understand why epsilon < t is a contradiction since t > 0? Is the epsilon step necessary? Since you have already proven that the infimum is larger or equal to one.

Comment: @man $0<\epsilon <t$ for all $t \in (0,1)$ is a contradiction because there are points in $(0,1)$ which are less than $\epsilon$.